# python, dash - some element in a dataframe has HTML syntax

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to make a table in a web application using Dash in Python.

I first take data from SQL database then I make a table from the data.

But some of the elements from the table have HTML syntax.

Ex) pandas dataframe

[image: ex]

Are there any ways of applying those syntax to the dash table?
I couldn't figure out how to deal with this HTML syntax in some elements.
All I can come up with is just to remove them,
but I want to use this syntax if possible.
Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using DangerouslySetInnerHTML.